# How to configure gradle cache to share common cached dependencies between projects?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After some months of use on a server with an automated generation system which generates different apks depending on inputs (but all the apks has the same libraries and dependencies), i got 300.000 subdirectories with it's own subdirectories and files gradle cache folders. All of them have more or less the same cached dependencies and files, duplicated.

Are some gradle cache files shared with all the projects? or are cloned for every project?

If you have 10 project which uses the same remote dependencies, for example, will gradle share some of these dependencies between the 10 projects or will clone the dependencies generating a lot of non necessary folders?

**How that works? can you configure gradle to share common dependencies between projects without cloning folders?**

I hope this can be achieved...